# cakephp pass string to controler

Tags: cakephp

I have this procedure where I need to process a text file. 
For the user to pick a file, I'm using this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->file('prodfile'); ?>
```

which provides a Browser button and an input with the path to the selected file.

After the user Browses for the file, then click on my link to trigger the method.

How can I add the string value on 'prodfile' input to a a link as this one?:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Process File'), array('controller' => 'qcas', 'action' => 'loadProdFromFile', 'dataFile' => $this->data['Project']['prodfile'], 'dirId' => $dirs['id']),  null, __('Please confirm you want to Load Production from File for Dir %s?', $dirs['dir_dataname'])); ?>
```

Tried the former, but since I'm not submitting the form, the value on 'prodfile' does not reach the controller.

How do i pass the string value on this file input to the controller? (Only need the string to parse and build a rightful path on the controller).

Update: I'm currently getting my feet wet with Ajax to accomplish this, but if anybody can suggest a different approach, please do.

Can you help?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Without ajax, using javascript I've managed to pass the string (full path to a file ) for parsing to the server via params on the triggering link.

1.- User picks up a file

```
<?php echo $this->Form->file('prodfile', array('onchange' => "getFile();")); ?>
(getFile() only saves current href on my links - step 3-)
```

2.- User manually copies the full path into a text input. (not ellegant but solved my problem).

```
echo $this->Form->input('Project.fullPathInput', array('label' => 'Copied Path', 'id' => 'fullPath', 'onchange' => "assignPath();"));
(assignPath() updates href on all my original links with the fullpath -since I don't know which one the user will click-
```

3.- This is the original link (several of these are dinamically created

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('LFF'), array('controller' => 'qcas', 'action' => 'loadProdFromFile', 'dirId' => $dirs['id']), array('name' => 'lff', 'id' => 'lff' . $i));

    function getFile() {
        document.getElementById('fullPath').value = '';
        var sHref = document.getElementsByName('lff');
        var len = sHref.length;
        // only the first time, save original hRef
        if ( preValues.length == 0) {   
            for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
                preValues[i] = sHref[i].href;
            }
        } else {
            for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
                sHref[i].href = preValues[i];
            }
        }
    }        

    function assignPath() {
        var finalPath = document.getElementById('fullPath').value;
        var sHref = document.getElementsByName('lff');
        var len = sHref.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
            sHref[i].href = sHref[i].href + '/filePath:'+finalPath;
        }        
    }
```

Just wanted to share in case somebody faces something similar.

Actually I've remade the whole thing using jQuery ajax but without the user picking a file. (as a second option for the user).